# How to improve Google Load Balancer performance with GKE over HTTPS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

I am moving Heroku to Google Cloud Platform and currently I'm running 3 n1-highcpu-4 nodes GKE cluster to test the setup and my application. The cluster was built using default configuration (except for preemptible nodes On). To create Ingres, LB (with NEG balancing) and use Google managed SSL certificate I closely followed these guides:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/container-native-load-balancing#create_service

Everything worked flawlessly out-of-box until I started load testing.

Our web application is collecting data from sensors, sent to it over HTTP(S) POST. I used loader.io for testing and this cluster was processing roughly 30k requests per second with under 200ms response time over HTTP. However, when I switched to HTTPS and repeated testing, performance dropped dramatically to less than 4k RPS with 1.7s-4s response time.

I tried to run more pods, add new nodes; send more requests to LB from loader.io; configure keep-alive / idle timeouts; a few kernel tweaks, but non of those helped to step over 4k RPS barriers. Even replacing the app with nginx container and testing its static welcome page had the same results.

Stackdriver GCLB metrics show frontend latency around 10ms and 8s backend latency. However, metrics from my application show that requests take normally between 20ms and 700ms.

`ingress.yml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: collector-non-prod
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: non-prod-cluster-ip
#    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "collector-dev,collector-staging"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: events-dev.xxx.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: collector-dev
              servicePort: 80
    - host: events-staging.xxx.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: collector-staging
              servicePort: 80
```

`service.yml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: collector-dev
  labels:
    environment: dev
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"backend-config-non-prod"}}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: collector
    environment: dev
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

`backend-config.yml` is simply this:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: backend-config-non-prod
spec:
  timeoutSec: 60
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 60
```

I would appreciate much any recommendations on improving HTTPS performance and decreasing requests latency, or helping me to investigate further. I am stuck at the moment :( Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that traffic is load balancing to your backends, you are stuck with a compute-intensive task, SSL Termination and offloading, which involves encryption/decryption and certificate verification. This task is at the load balancer. This Google service is outside your control. You will not achieve the same performance as HTTP. You did not specify the size of the test packets. Assuming a 128 byte packet, there is a lot of cpu cycles spent for almost no data. Try testing with a realistic payload size (add the TCP packet size) that matches your real world and re-compare.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley. Average JSON payload is 1.2Kb. I tested with real data.

Comment: When you factor 1.2KB x 30K packets per second that is 288 Mbits per second. For HTTPS 1.2KB x 4K packets per second is 38 Mbits per second. Neither is a great number. If you actually meant 1.2 Kilobits per packet (that is what Kb means), then those are bad performance numbers.

Comment: Where is the testing servers located and where is the K8s cluster located? Can you try a different test within the same region as the cluster? Remove the Internet as a variable in your tests.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 1.2KB payload, not kilobits. The cluster is in Australis, loader.io is in US. I tested with Locust (from Australia) and got slightly better results: 4.4k RPS, same latency.

Another thing I found, if I run the test at 4k RPS and below, then latency drops to 200ms. So, it must be something with throughput as you mentioned, @JohnHanley.

Looking at combined metrics from Stackdriver, LB and my app, traffic flows like this: hit LB GFE (~ 10ms) - (spend a few seconds somewhere) - arrive to the app (20ms-700ms p/request) - and back = 1.7s-4s response time.

Comment: If possible try a new cluster in the US, test in the same region meaning in GCP for both sides to remove the Internet. Your numbers do not make sense based upon my experience. Something is wrong, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: As a test, I would try setting up a self-managed SSL cert on your GKE cluster and see if you get different results.

Comment: Also, make sure your GKE cluster and your NEG are in the same region/zone.Check VPC flow logs to make sure your packets aren't being routed somewhere weird.  I can't think of anything else, there's something misaligned somewhere.

Comment: Thank you @TravisWebb. Tested in the same region as loader.io (North America) with my own certificate. My app results were the same. Tried nginx image, 10k clients per second GET /: HTTP was 10k RPS @ 16ms, HTTPS was 3k @ 1.3s. No luck :(

Comment: The published numbers for the Google HTTP(S) Load Balancer is 1 million requests per second. Your numbers clearly show an issue. I would open an Issue Tracker item. With luck, an engineer will help with internal testing. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers